# Writing a graphical interface in python

Tags: python, gui

is there any addition to python, or some program that has a graphical interface and translates it into code in the same file, i.e. this file can be opened graphically, and then continue working with it as with text.
It be site and not use Python, but have?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think OP is asking for a RAD IDE (Rapid Development Integrated Development Environment) that allows you to draw a UI and it builds the necessary code for you.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell what you're asking, but my best guess is you're looking for something like Jupyter-notebooks.

Jupyter-notebook is an interactive python shell that allows you to work in "notebooks".  The best way to describe them is they allow you write "blocks" of code and run them independently of the other blocks.  It is very similar to matlab's code editor if you have every used the blocks in that.  It has support for displaying matplotlib charts inline, and puts formatting on pandas dataframes.

See: https://jupyter.org/

Comment: I agree the question is vague and Jupyter may be a good option. The answer would be better, however, if you would add a little description of what Jupyter notebooks are and a link to where they can be found.